# isset check inside foreach loop

Tags: php, post, foreach, isset

Apologies if this is a dumb question, but I'm learning PHP right now and I'm having an issue regarding doing an isset check of a $_POST value that may or may not exist depending on whether the user has submitted a form or not.

If I do the following outside the context of a foreach loop, I get an undefined index message(when the form has not yet been submitted), as I would expect:

```
if ($_POST['dorm'] == "somethingrandom"){ ... }
```

As I understand it, I get this error because that $_POST value doesn't exist and I need to run it through an isset() or !empty() check instead of just assuming it exists. But if I have the exact same code inside a foreach loop, I do not get the error:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<select name="dorm">
<?php foreach ($DORMS as $dorm){
    if ($_POST['dorm'] == $dorm){
        echo "<option selected value=\"$dorm\">$dorm</option>";
    } else {
        echo "<option value=\"$dorm\">$dorm</option>";
    }
}
?> // end php tag
</select>
</form>
```

Again, the above code creates no errors, even though I'm not doing any isset() or !empty() checks. I'm just wondering if this is the expected behavior, and if so, why?

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: I get undefined index inside AND outside foreach loops, as expected, using php 5.3.10. what version are you using?

Comment: there may be nothing in the for each loop.. :)

Comment: Could you just echo the values of $_POST['dorm'] and $dorm in the foreach loop then you can know what values are comes.

Comment: You missed closed php tag after closing bracket of the if statement.

Comment: your foreach dosent work for once

Comment: check my answer. if you have any issue update me. i will help you @user927839

Comment: $DORMS is an array I have set that includes 9 different names of dorms. Sorry, I didn't include it above, but it does exist in my code. And I know it is going through the loop, because the select box is rendered properly on the page. Thank you Nathan for taking the time to offer that example, but I'm more concerned right now with figuring out why I'm getting undefined outside the foreach loop and not inside it. Marc: I'm using PHP 5.4.12 locally in WAMP. Thanks guys for all the replies!

Comment: To anyone who is wondering, chanchal118's answer helped me figure this out. For whatever reason, the notice doesn't appear on the rendered page when the error occurs inside my foreach loop. But if you look at the page source in Firebug, the errors are there. Thanks again everyone for the help. Not allowed to upvote yet or I would.

Comment: @user927839 You can accept the answer if you feel that right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No notice or error inside foreach is expected when `$DORMS` is empty. Code inside `foreach` does not get executed when `$DORMS` is empty. When you have some value in `$DORMS` you can see that notice using [chrome dev tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) or [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/).

[image]

EDIT

Notice has nothing to do with `foreach` loop. You do not see the notice because it is generated inside a `<select>` element in html. Browser is not showing any normal text that is inside `<select>`. If your `foreach` loop was inside a `<p>` html element you could see that message as the browser would output that.

```
<p>
<?php foreach ($DORMS as $dorm){
    if ($_POST['dorm'] == $dorm){
        echo "<option selected value=\"$dorm\">$dorm</option>";
    } else {
        echo "<option value=\"$dorm\">$dorm</option>";
    }
}
?>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. $DORMS is an array with 9 strings assigned to it. And I'm pretty sure the foreach code is getting executed because the select element is rendered properly on the page. I'm just not getting the error message as I'd expect.

Comment: Then you can see that error message using firebug or chrome dev tools. It is inside page source.

Comment: Yes, you are right! The errors do show up in firebug. It's just weird that the notice pops up on the page when the the code is outside the foreach loop, but not when it is inside. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is not weird. If this 'foreach' loop was inside `<p>` html tag you could see that message. It is inside `<select>`. Normal text inside select do no show in browser.

Comment: I guess I meant it was weird to me. But now that you explained it, it makes a lot of sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the form is submitted by POST method in two ways

```
if($_POST){
   ...
}
```

or

```
if(isset($_POST['your_variable'])){
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yogesh. That makes sense but I'm trying to figure out why I'm not getting an undefined notice when I don't run a check inside my foreach loop.

Comment: It is actually throwing the warning message but since you have used select tag the warning message gets underneath it. As select tag is designed to show only the contained option tag, the text(here warning message) apart from option tags are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason for this would be because the array `$DORMS` is empty. In that case, the `foreach` loop will never execute the body, so it will never try to access the nonexisting `$_POST['dorm']`.

What you should do is set another variable to the selected dorm, and protect that with an `isset` check:

```
$dorm_input = isset($_POST['dorm']) ? $_POST['dorm] : null;
```

Then in your loop check `if ($dorm == $dorm_input)`

Comment: What about the default case when no post is performed. In that case select will not be created .

Comment: Thanks Barmar for your response. That makes sense and I'm sure it would work. I'm just trying to understand conceptually why I'm not getting an error when I'm not running an isset check inside my foreach loop. I didn't include it in my original post, but the $DORMS array has 9 string values assigned to it. I'm pretty sure the foreach loop is executing because the select is rendered properly on the page.

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening because it is not getting into the loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <?php
    if (isset($_POST['dorm'])) 
  {
    $DORMS = $rows; //array from database
    foreach($DORMS  as $dorm){
         if($row['dorm'] == $_POST['dorm']){
              $isSelected = ' selected="selected"'; // if the option submited in form is as same as this row we add the selected tag
         } else {
              $isSelected = ''; // else we remove any tag
         }
         echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'".$isSelected.">".$row['name']."</option>";
       }
  }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As other says empty $DORMS may be the reason for not getting notice. For check on your code you can do something like .

```
if (is_array($DORMS) && sizeof($DORMS) > 0) {
    foreach ($DORMS as $dorm) {
        if (isset($_POST['dorm']) && $_POST['dorm'] == $dorm){
            echo "<option selected value=\"$dorm\">$dorm</option>";
        } else {
            echo "<option value=\"$dorm\">$dorm</option>";
        }
    }
}
```